# Responsive just active when insert code <style> in page

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming

I don't understand! Please help me...

I use Wordpress and I had:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

but responsive not working when I insert

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') ?>/responsive.css"/>
```

or use a function to call it out, The code is still visible but responsive not working...

After that, I try to insert all code from file responsive.css into header.php with `<style>` tag then it's working..

I want to it's working without need insert code from the file into header.php.. Please help me !! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the proper functions to enqueue scripts and stylesheets.  I've added a dependency for bootstrap in this function so that is loads after bootstrap has loaded its stylesheet.  Place this code in your functions.php file, I've added in the Bootstrap CSS from a CDN as an example.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles');

function child_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/responsive.css', array('bootstrap') );

}
```

Comment: it's not working :( , I added into function.php but it's not display...

Comment: How are you enqueuing all your other CSS files?  You should be using the wp_enqueue_style function for all CSS files.  I've added in Bootstrap CDN as an example in my answer.

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn you're welcome, make sure you these functions for adding javascript and CSS to ensure things work smoothly :)